# How to listen to a C#.NET activeX control's event in vb6

Tags: c#, .net, vb6, activex, com-interop

The .net control has been referenced and added to the vb6 project. It also shows the events that I have in the interface. However, vb6 is not registering to the events and I do not know why. I have read several dozen articles on the subject, used code from a working .Net Control/vb6. This is my first round robin with Events so its probably something very small I'm missing, but here's the code:

C#.NET

```
[ComVisible (true)]
[Guid(CustomerCreditControl.EventsId)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface ICustomerCreditControlEvents
{
    [DispId(1)]
    void Test();
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(CustomerCreditControl.InterfaceId)]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
public interface ICustomerCreditControl
{
    void SetAccount(string customerNumber, int generatorId);
    string CreditHold { get; }
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(CustomerCreditControl.ClassId)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(ICustomerCreditControlEvents))]
public partial class CustomerCreditControl : UserControl, ICustomerCreditControl
{
     public delegate void TestEventHandler();
     public event TestEventHandler TestEvent;
    [ComRegisterFunction()]
    private static void Register(Type t)
    {
        ComRegistration.RegisterControl(t, "");
    }

    [ComUnregisterFunction()]
    private static void Unregister(Type t)
    {
        ComRegistration.UnregisterControl(t);
    }
    public CustomerCreditControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void SetAccount(string customerNumber, int generatorId)
    {
        _customer = RCI.DataAccess.DataFactory.Current.AccountService.GetCustomer(customerNumber.Trim());           
        SetAccount(_customer, generatorId);
    }
    public void btnNewSalesOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TestEvent != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test Event Fired");
            TestEvent();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("TestEvent = null");

        string[] SOI = {"a","b","c"};
        MessageBox.Show(SOI.ToString());
        OnNewSalesOrder(ref SOI);
    }
 }
```

VB6

```
Private Sub customerCreditInfo_Test()
     MsgBox "Test 2"
End Sub
```

The vb6 code recognizes the test event, but it does not register to the event. The control is placed on a vb6 form. I have 'MsgBox "Test 2"' just as a test. The tlb is referenced by the project and the activeX is added to the toolbox components. I have unregistered this dll from windows and gone through and removed all instances from the registry. I am using regasm /register /codebase /tlb to register the dll.

Using Visual Studio 2008, .net 2.0 and compiling on a Windows 7 machine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
   public event TestEventHandler TestEvent;
```

to

```
   public event TestEventHandler Test;
```

This is to match the event method definition in your source interface. Then fire the event as `Test()`.

Comment: Thanks, shortly after posting this I had seen this error and corrected it. Sometimes after looking at code you have to step away and look at it again :)  Thanks for the response!